# Yii2 ValidatePage to give empty output on wrong page number

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to fetch a list of products from a table using my yii2 app and send it accross as a json to lazyload on scroll from the front end. I am using the searchmodel class. Now when data ends, last page data is being send again, i.e., if i have hundred records, the calls for page numbers above 5 would repeatedly send the same data as page number 4. How do i prevent it.
PS: Confused about the usage of the validatePage flag reading the documentation.

Here is my code of the controller.

```
public function actionAjaxIndex()
{

  $searchModel = new productsS();
    $response = (object) ['status' => 0];
  $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $response->status = 1;
        $response->data = array();
        foreach($dataProvider->models as $row){
            foreach($row as $key=>$value){
                $customerDetail[$key] = $value;
            }
            array_push($response->data, $customerDetail);
        }
        return json_encode($response);
}
```

Can somebody help with the best possible solution to go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable [`$validatePage`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$validatePage-detail) for your data provider. This setting overwrites page if it is outside of range (so if you have 4 pages of records, but you request 5th page, pagination will automatically switch to 4th page - every page outside of range will display results for last page).

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->pagination->validatePage = false;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. You have no idea how much you saved me.